# pasar un array con swiftyJson a modelo usando JSON con init (SWIFT 4.2)

Tags: json, swift, swift2, swift3, swift4

tengo un JSON donde hay un array de imagenes, quiero usar SwiftyJson para traer ese array... y en el modelo uso un inicializador -> init(json: JSON), asi al iterar con:

```
       let suggestions = json["industries", "Suggestions"].arrayValue.map {CategorySuggestion(json: $0)}
                self?.category.append(contentsOf: suggestions)
                self?.createCollectionView.reloadData()
```

me trae el resultado del json y lo coloca dentro de mi modelo pasándole el dato de category, los datos pasan a excepción del array...
el resultado que obtengo en consola es este....

```
        title: "Feed Them All", defaultImage: "https://images.xcerw.com/photo-1530984662486-75aee21a673e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=58d3ac2b6f6678e0d4b4ddcb8b6c9c70&auto=format&fit=crop&w=763&q=80", images: [""], subCategory: []
                                 {
```

pero images aparece vacío ( images: [" "]... como puedo rellenar ese array?

```html
    "Suggestions": [
            {
                "defaultImage": "https://images.xcerw.com/photo-1530984662486-75aee21a673e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=58d3ac2b6f6678e0d4b4ddcb8b6c9c70&auto=format&fit=crop&w=763&q=80",
                "images": [
                    "https://images.xcerw.com/photo-1526743891018-fc876a01332c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6b4c1219f977d8b10a44a58bb749dd44&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80",
                    "https://images.xcerw.com/photo-1518830686998-b8847466b372?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=226c6e93e81c6f2968bf51966fe397a5&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1084&q=80",
                    "https://images.xcerw.com/photo-1521294102048-6cb73602dc43?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=62290477f0f0db4d5be6ad7834781f39&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80",
                    "https://images.xcerw.com/photo-1469648034646-7911874fe62b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6733f519f46551f66241abe32a57d249&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1038&q=80",
                    "https://images.xcerw.com/photo-1523813301608-f54a198f6b5f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=b77895dac2588da7b541a4ba92f11c00&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80",
                    "https://images.xcerw.com/photo-1525333045628-55625a2c385f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=b6e0cac323501a4788b28b2e3a9a290c&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1189&q=80",
                    "https://images.xcerw.com/photo-1474600056930-615c3d706456?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=7f4bd9ccbf3cb4ac03db0f64fc12f5ae&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1052&q=80",
                    "https://images.xcerw.com/photo-1532347231146-80afc9e3df2b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5b79c9f1c5c919af61ac2e1d955a2bf9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=632&q=80",
                    "https://images.xcerw.com/photo-1520066975094-c321ec00637d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=22e2ff8395f856d919845fd248766ef3&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80"
                ],
                "Title": "Feed Them All"
            }
```

y mi modelo

```
  struct CategorySuggestion {
    var title: String
    var defaultImage: String
    var images: [String] // <- quiero ingresar aqui el array de imagenes
    var subCategory: [SubCategorySuggestion]

  init(json: JSON) {
      title = json["Title"].stringValue
      defaultImage = json["default"].stringValue
      images = [json["images"].stringValue]
      subCategory = []
     }
 }
```

Comment: hice un cambio en el modelo... en vez de [String] -> puse [JSON] se va de la siguiente manera...  var images:  [JSON].... y en el inicializador......      images = json["images"].arrayValue... con esto ya se pasan al modelo y funciona bien....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifiqué la estructura de la siguiente manera, con esto ya pude ingresar el array en cada objeto sin problemas

```
struct CategorySuggestion {
     var title: String
     var defaultImage: String
     var images:[JSON]
     var subCategory: [SubCategorySuggestion]

   init(json: JSON) {
     title = json["Title"].stringValue
     defaultImage = json["default"].stringValue
     images = json["images"].arrayValue
     subCategory = []
   }
 }
```