# Como parsear un JSON con array de diccionarios dentro de otro array con Swift y alamofire

Tags: swift, xcode, realm, alamofire

estoy intentando pasear un objeto con alamofire, y todo bien hasta que tengo que tratar con array de diccionarios que tengo dentro de ese mismo objeto. Creo que tengo un problema con el modelo, pero no estoy seguro y al no encontrar docu me he decidido por preguntar.

Clase modelo:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper

class Constelation : Mappable {

\\ aqui el typalias lo creo para intentar parsear el array de diccionario

typealias dictionary = [[String : String]]

  var itemId : String?
  var name : String?
  var subtitle : String?
  var body : String?
  var imagen : String?
  var poster : String?

\\ aqui stars me da un error diciéndome que no conforma el protocolo RealmCollectionValue

  var stars = List<Stars>()
  var objects : Array<dictionary>?

  required init?(map: Map) {

  }

  func mapping(map: Map) {
      itemId <- map["itemId"]
      name <- map["name"]
      subtitle <- map["subtitle"]
      body <- map["body"]
      imagen <- map["imagen"]
      poster <- map["poster"]
      stars <- map["stars"]
      objects <- map["objects"]
  }
}

  class Stars: Constelation {

  @objc dynamic var nameStarst: String?


  required convenience init?() {
      self.init()
  }
}
```

La clase ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage
import AlamofireObjectMapper

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var constellations: [Constelation]?
    var stars: [Stars]?
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.setupUI()
      self.setupData()
   }

   func setupUI() {
      self.table.delegate = self
      self.table.dataSource = self
   }

   func setupData() {
      APIController.requestConstelations { (constellationArray, error) in
            print("Terminé de sacar url \(constellationArray?.first?.imagen)")
           print("saco el item \(constellationArray?.first?.itemId)")
           if error != nil {
              print("error")
           }
           else {
                print()
              for x in Stars {
                     print(x)
                  }
           }
       }
    }

}
```

cuando intento imprimir el array me da nil o el valor de la referencia en memoria. ¿la cuestión es si tengo que crear una propiedad en el modelo de datos o por el contrario es utilizando la clase constelación y algún protocolo?

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: checa esto... espero te pueda ayudar... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/192813/pasar-un-array-con-swiftyjson-a-modelo-usando-json-con-init-swift-4-2/192891#192891

Comment: el error de protocolo es porque necesitas agregar la clase del delegado en tu clase... por ejemplo al setear self a un collectionView ( collectionView.delegate = self), si no has agregado los delegados ("UICollectionViewDelegate") te marcara que este view controller no tiene el protocolo para poder asignarle el delegado dando el error que te aparece,  el item "stars" que creaste necesita el protocolo para poder funcionar...

Comment: igual intenta usar SwiftyJSON, para poder inicializar tu estructura como json, como en el ejemplo que te puse,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No comprendo del todo la estructura del json que intentas parsear, no obstante te adjunto una posible respuesta.

Si tenemos un json como el siguiente:

```
{
 "itemId":"1",
 "name":"Estrella1",
 ...
 "objects":[  
           {  
            "subItem":"2",
            "subName":"SubItem"
           },
           ...
           ]
}
```

Nuestros modelos con ObjectMapper serían:

```
class Constelation : Mappable {
   var itemId : String = ""
   var name : String = ""
   ...
   var objects : Array<Star>?

   init() {}
   required init?(map: Map) {}

   func mapping(map: Map) {
      itemId <- map["itemId"]
      name <- map["name"]
      ...
      objects <- map["objects"]
   }
}

class Star : Mappable {
   var subItem : String = ""
   var subName : String = ""

   init() {}
   required init?(map: Map) { }

   func mapping(map: Map) {
     subItem <- map["subItem"]
     subName <- map["subName"]
   }
}
```

Y del lado del WebService sería

```
let responseService = Mapper<Constelation>().map(JSON: json)
print(responseService?.objects?[0].subItem)
```

En el caso de que tu json sea un  array de array del lado del WebService la instrucción sería :

```
let responseService = Mapper<Constelation>().mapArray(JSONObject: json)
print(responseService?[0].objects?[0].subItem)
```

Saludos espero te ayude